# which php 7.2 function and which encryption algorithm should i use in encryption to obtain 16 hex characters in ciphertext?

Tags: php, encryption

i need to encrypt 16 hex characters and obtain 16 hex characters in ciphertext,
i have tried des using openssl what should i do(add or change) to obtain 16 hexadecimal characters in cipher text after encrypting 16 hex characters.

```
<?php

$key = 'qwetyasdftrewqasdcxz';

function my_encrypt($data, $key) {

    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = '11111111';
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'des', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);

    return base64_encode($encrypted );
}

function my_decrypt($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = '11111111';
    $encrypted_data=base64_decode($data);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'des', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
}
$password_plain = 0x34adeb98761a2b;
echo $password_plain . "<br>";
$password_encrypted = my_encrypt($password_plain, $key);
echo $password_encrypted . "<br>";
$password_decrypted = my_decrypt($password_encrypted, $key);
echo $password_decrypted . "<br>";
```

Comment: i have made some changes, i need your help please. @AnanthaRajuC

Comment: In general - you can't.  At least not securely, which is the whole point of encrypting something.  You always need an IV or nonce which is, at least, another 12 bytes (24 hex chars).  Don't use DES either, use AES.  DES can be trivially broken.

Answer (score 0):

> i need to encrypt 16 hex characters and obtain 16 hex characters in ciphertext,

Looks like an example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Why do you need 16 hex characters for both input and output? As it stands, your operational requirements are already doomed.

It appears to me that you're storing passwords. Encryption is usually the wrong tool for the job. Look into [password hashing](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016) instead.

But if you do need to encrypt a string, and you want your encryption to be secure, you must accept that your output will be longer than your input.

The reason is that, by itself, encryption is [vulnerable to chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken). You need some way of assuring the *integrity* of the encrypted message to prevent attacks which compromise a message's *confidentiality*.

The best thing to do is question your requirements. "Why do I need the input to be 16 hex characters? Why do I need the output to be 16 hex characters?"

Also, don't use DES or Triple-DES.

Comment: i am working on energy meter token generation system, my token requres three inputs (meterID in hex , token and unit value in dec which i will convert later to hex). After concatenation of three inputs i will convert it to hex which will be 16 hex characters, then i need to encrypt the hex value to obtain 16 hex ciphertext characters. The ciphertext will be converted back to decimal to obtain a generated token. on the other side(on energy meter) i will simply reverse the process. Any suggestions or alternative?